# Directory with thousands of files can't be deleted on MacOS Mojave

Tags: directory, macos, delete

I am running on macOS Mojave version 10.14.6.

I wrote a program that creates files. It had a run away accident and created a huge number files in a directory. I don't know how many files it created and I don't know how I would figure that out. When enter the directory and run `ls` it just hangs.

I run the command

```
rm -f BIGNASTYDIRECTORY
```

but that hangs, even if I let it run for 24 hours. If I run top on the rm process it shows it in the "STUCK" state.

Fortunately, I can rename the directory via the `mv` command. If I move the directory the trash it seems to slowly, slowly be making progress. I think it would take a month to complete.

I would ignore this for a while but it seems to be keeping time machine from running. It hangs in the "Preparing Backup" stage for days.

Is there some way I could quickly blow away this directory?

Comment: I have never used macOS so I may be wrong but by `STUCK` state do you mean uninterruptible sleep? Is this directory an external mount? Can you use `lsof` to check which processes use this directory?

Comment: Not sure what is meant by stuck showing up in the top output. Here is what somebody else posted : stuck means that the process is currently un-interruptible which usually is the case if the process is waiting for a disk or network data block to be read (or similar low-level stuff). Technically speaking the process is executing in kernel space (aka Unix kernel) and can not be interrupted (so even a kill -9 wouldn't have any impact). Usually these stuck states only last milliseconds (as you can see in top as well because the number of stuck processes changes with every display cycle).

Comment: lsof appears to hang as well.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like uninterruptible sleep. Try lsof with -n https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81140/why-is-lsof-on-os-x-so-ridiculously-slow